# Delete values in one table based on values in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to execute this statement to delete records from the F30026 table that followed the rules listed.. I'm able to run a select * from and a select count(*) from with that statement, but when running it with a delete it doesn't like it.. it gets lost on the 'a' that is to define F30026 as table a

```
delete from CRPDTA.F30026 a
where exists (
select b.IMLITM from CRPDTA.F4101 b
where a.IELITM=b.IMLITM
and substring(b.IMGLPT,1,2) not in ('FG','IN','RM'));
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean "gets lost"

Comment: Sorry, had to give up access to that machine for a moment and couldn't recall the exact error that was being thrown.

"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'a'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an inner join to me, see [MySQL - DELETE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html)

```
delete a from CRPDTA.F30026 as a
inner join CRPDTA.F4101 as b on a.IELITM = b.IMLITM
where substring(b.IMGLPT, 1, 2) not in ('FG', 'IN', 'RM')
```

Please note the alias syntax `as a` and `as b`.

Comment: Appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the 'exists' function, you can match the id (like you do in the where clause):

```
delete from CRPDTA.F30026 a
where a.IELITM IN (
select b.IMLITM from CRPDTA.F4101 b
where a.IELITM=b.IMLITM
and substring(b.IMGLPT,1,2) not in ('FG','IN','RM'));
```

Comment: Running this statement threw an exception error on the 'a' in line 1 as my statement was.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you really want, all IELITMs which meet your criteria.

```
delete from CRPDTA.F30026
where IELITM IN (
select IMLITM from CRPDTA.F4101 
where substring(IMGLPT,1,2) not in ('FG','IN','RM'));
```

Comment: Running this statement threw an exception error on the 'a' in line 1.